# Azure SignalR Service with Asp.net 4.6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, signalr, asp.net-core-2.0

I have project in asp.net 4.6. I want to use Azure SignalR Service in my project as it is more efficient than backplane, but it seems like Azure SignalR Service are available for Asp.net core only. Is there a way to use Azure SignalR Service in asp.net 4.6 as well. Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure SignalR Service doesn't support ASP.NET SignalR but it's in the plan, see the issue here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/issues/101. For now you'll have to move to ASP.NET Core if you want to use the service.

Comment: Thanks Ken. Could you please let me know how much it reliable to use Azure services in load balancing. Also which is better signalR backplane or azure signalR services.

Comment: It's recommended to use Azure SignalR service, with service you don't need to set up backplane and load balancers by yourself.

Comment: You can also just use HTTP to talk to the SignalR endpoints (from your backend). The SignalR package has some code samples you can take inspiration from. That way you're completely unrestricted in terms of platform choices.

Answer (score 2):

[The latest release of SignalR (2.4.0)](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/releases/tag/2.4.0) allows to use Azure SignalR Service

> This is the RTM build of ASP.NET SignalR 2.4.0
>
> This release brings support for the Azure SignalR Service, see the
>   Azure SignalR Samples repo for a sample application and tutorial for
>   deploying an ASP.NET SignalR application using the Azure SignalR
>   Service.